# Jenkins - how to use property defined in a groovy file loaded by Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Because we have several pipelines that have similar logic and need some common properties, we created a groovy file and put some common methods properties in it.
But we found the properties defined in the groovy file can't be accessed.

Here is our groovy file: common.groovy:

```
def MyProp="value"

def myMethod() {
  //Fail here
  println MyProp
}

return this
```

JenkinsFile:

```
node('test') {
  checkout scm

  def jenkinsCommon = load "common.groovy"

  jenkinsCommon.myMethod()
  // Below also fail
  println jenkinsCommon.MyProp
}
```

We got the following exception when running jobs with this Jenkinsfile:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MyProp for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at Script1.myMethod(Script1.groovy:4)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:33)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor286.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

How to define and use the property in a groovy file loaded by pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a variable defined outside the method then you have to annotate it with `@Field` annotation, e.g.

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
def myProp="value"

def myMethod() {
  println myProp
}
```

Every Groovy script gets compiled to a class that extends `groovy.lang.Script` class and each method defined in a script is compiled as a class level method, while the rest of script body is executed inside `Script.run()` method.

It means that when your `myMethod` tries to access `myProp` it fails, because `myProp` is compiled as a local variable available inside `Script.run()` method. This `@Field` annotation promotes given variable to a class level variable, so it can be accessed from any method defined in the script.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. After adding "@Field" annotation, we got exception "java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector" at the line of load "common.groovy", could you give any suggestion on this NotSerializableException? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Polaris I guess it was caused by missing import. My mistake, code sample updated.

Comment: Once again @SzymonStepniak comes through with a critical Jenkins detail, clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `def MyProp="value"` with `env.MyProp="value"` It will work !

Comment: Thanks @codeGeass. Yes, use env.MyProp can resolve current issue. But because we also want to share some complex variables (map, list, etc) through the common.groovy, we want to see if there is any other solution